# How to upload files in Protractor- error( Done, upload failed)?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
    var fileToUpload = './trial.txt';
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(by.buttonText('Upload')).click();
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: what's wrong with this code? any error?

Comment: Did you search for your error on StackOverflow or elsewhere? What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov this code works fine when I try to update an image, but the problem is when I am trying to upload a document, it's going to the location where the profile update happens and not where the document upload should happen.

Comment: based on the code snippet you provided, I don't see profile updates code